# Chrome extension - "File_get_contents" of a PDF file, open in a tab

Tags: pdf, google-chrome-extension

is it possible, to get the file-content of an pdf, that is opened in google chrome.

I started with an chrome extension, permission "activetabs" etc...

Read the HTML Code of the tab is working, but i need directly the file data,
like file_get_contents($pdf) in php.

How does this work? Have somebody a experiance?

Comment: I'm afraid Chrome doesn't provide any such API for extensions. You may file it on [crbug.com](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) for a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Now i have found a solution:

Javascript:

```
//Read file
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'file:///C:/Scource_File.pdf', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.send();


//Send file
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('server-method', 'upload');
fd.append('file', blob);
xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.example.com/get_file_via_post.php', false);
xhr.send(fd);
```